# Asking about replacement/change of Micro-USB and USB-C on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a small Bluetooth device that is currently in need of a replacement charge port. it is currently using a Micro-USB port, but I thought I might be able to upgrade to a USB-C port instead (purely for the slightly hardier design).

Is this the place to ask about this?

[image]

My question is sort of a two parter:

Is it viable to replace the Micro-USB port with a USB-C port to charge my device, and if so, how should it be done (Micro-USB and USB-C have different pin/connection points to connect to the board)

Comment: What exactly is going to be your question?  We won’t be able to answer if it will be compatible, since we don’t have access to the device, or the replacement part specifications.  You will have to be more precise on what your potential question would be exactly by performing an [edit] to your question

Comment: Is the replacement something that you are going to do yourself?  Do you know that it *can* be replaced?

Comment: @RayButterworth that's the question. I am aiming to replace it myself, but I don't know enough to know if it can be done, or if it's even viable

Comment: It is probably surface mounted parts (SMD components) as most recent electronics are. its not impossible to replace these parts, but it is not easy. You will most likely damage the board traces if you do not have the proper tools, possibly modify the case (if there is room for the new connector), and hope that the USB-C has the same pin configuration as the original USB-micro connector. What do you consider your time worth to you?